# WebApplication at "site url" coul not be found

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2007

i have made window application, which checks new announcements on sharepoint 2007 site, if any new announcemnt is found it shows it as link in my win application.
application is running fine on my server machine, but when i try to run my window application from normal machine it gives me:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The
>   Web application at
>   http://Server-Name:Port-Num/lists/announcements/Allitems.aspx could not be found. Verify that you
>   have typed the URL correctly. If the
>   URL should be serving existing
>   content, the system administrator may
>   need to add a new request URL mapping
>   to the intended application.

this machine exists on LAN, as i can access site from my browser, but when it comes to win application it gives me the above error on following line:

```
string rawurl = "http://192.168.1.105:1625/";
SPSite site = new SPSite(rawurl);  // this line gives error
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs in the 12 hive for detailed error information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should throw an exception because the Server Object Model you are using like `SPSite`, `SPWeb` will not work unless it's on the server either web application or windows application.

If you want to get data from a remote sharepoint server you should use SharePoint Web Services.

This article will help you http://www.infoq.com/articles/swanson-moss-web-services
References:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/570a4734-d11e-4385-bb97-8625013ebe99/
- http://objectmix.com/sharepoint/296959-object-model-new-web-site-creation-remote-sharepoint-server.html

Answer (score 0):

make sure the **alternate access mapping** is correctly set

so if you can call a page with multiple name (machine name and alias like xxxx73 and portauat) note that   may only one works in visual studio so try to fix mapping in central admin or call the page with default main url.

for me noting this small tip, fix my problem in my Sharepoint 2010 UAT environment